# Azure Data Factory - source dataset fails with "path does not resolve to any file(s)" when sink to a different directory is in progress

Tags: azure-data-factory

We have an ADF pipeline with Copy activity to transfer data from Azure Table Storage to a JSON file in an Azure Blob Storage container. When the data transfer is in progress, other pipelines that use this dataset as a source fail with the following error "Job failed due to reason: Path does not resolve to any file(s)".

The dataset has a property that indicates the container directory. This property is populated by the trigger time of the pipeline copying the data, so it writes to a different directory in each run. The other failing pipelines use a directory corresponding to an earlier run of the pipeline copying the data and I have confirmed that the path does exist.

Anyone knows why this is happening and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your expression in directory and file textbox inside the dataset is not correct.

Check this link : [Azure data flow not showing / in path to data source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3a94d26a-a6fb-4e01-89c9-950b36ff90dd/azure-data-flow-not-showing-in-path-to-data-source?forum=AzureDataFactory)